# SSH not working through domain but fine if connected directly trough ddns

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

my situation is this:
home (router with configured ddns.net, (inner) port 22 mapped to 443 (just to avoid most firewalls) to expose my PC's on the internet, a ddns subscription and a domain subscription for "mydomain.com".

I want to be able to ssh my pc by `ssh dds@home.mydomain.com -p 443`
Currently I can succesfully access my pc by `ssh dds@myname.ddns.net -p 443`
The domain is configured to add a CNAME recod like this:
`home.mydomain.com CNAME myname.dyndns.net TTL 900`

But when using `home.mydomain.com` I get this error kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

If I `ping home.mydomain.com` It is resolved correctly (same ip as ping myname.ddns.net) and also I recive responses.

Comment: First thing Id try is to do ssh -v xxx@xxxxx..  to each address and compare the debug info - taking special care to see what keys are attempted.  It sounds to me like you may have a config file on the client to specify a different key set - so check if there is anything in ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config  overriding default key selection.